# How tensorflow model.weights works?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have defined a neural network model:

```
model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape = (15,)), # the input layer
    keras.layers.Dense(20, activation = 'relu'), #the hidden
    keras.layers.Dense(20, activation = 'relu'), #the hidden
    keras.layers.Dense(20, activation = 'relu'), #the hidden
    keras.layers.Dense(20, activation = 'relu'), #the hidden
    keras.layers.Dense(20, activation = 'relu'), #the hidden
    keras.layers.Dense(2) #The output layer
])
```

This the summary of the model:

```
Model: "sequential_7"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 flatten_7 (Flatten)         (None, 15)                0         
                                                                 
 dense_40 (Dense)            (None, 20)                320       
                                                                 
 dense_41 (Dense)            (None, 20)                420       
                                                                 
 dense_42 (Dense)            (None, 20)                420       
                                                                 
 dense_43 (Dense)            (None, 20)                420       
                                                                 
 dense_44 (Dense)            (None, 20)                420       
                                                                 
 dense_45 (Dense)            (None, 2)                 42        
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 2,042
Trainable params: 2,042
Non-trainable params: 0
```

After I training, I expected to get weights of the form:

16X20, 21X20, .... 21X2 because the const column the neural network has.

But when I actually measure the shapes of model.weights I actually get matrices

at the even columns and and vectors at the odd places:

```
mats = [np.array(w) for w in model.weights[0::2]]
vecs= [np.array(w) for w in model.weights[1::2]]
print([w.shape for w in mats])
print([w.shape for w in vecs])


[(15, 20), (20, 20), (20, 20), (20, 20), (20, 20), (20, 2)]
[(20,), (20,), (20,), (20,), (20,), (2,)]
```

My question is: Are the vectors here are just the zero lines of the mats that correspond to the const parameter at each layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vectors here are the biases that are defined for each `Dense` layer. Try outputting the weights of the first `Dense` layer for example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape = (15,)), # the input layer
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(20, activation = 'relu'), #the hidden
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(20, activation = 'relu'), #the hidden
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(20, activation = 'relu'), #the hidden
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(20, activation = 'relu'), #the hidden
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(20, activation = 'relu'), #the hidden
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2) #The output layer
])

print(model.layers[1].weights)
```

You should see the kernel weights and the biases. This corresponds to the description of the [Dense](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dense) layer:

> Dense implements the operation: output = activation(dot(input, kernel) + bias)

Comment: Thank you for solution. Do you know why model.predict(x_train) gives me valuse not between 0 and 1 as probabilities should be?

Comment: Your model's output layer is using a linear activation function. If you want values between 0 and 1  you can use a sigmoid activation function. If you want to convert the output to a vector of probabilities, you can use a softmax activation function. All depends on your use case.